# Youtube embed player default resolution

Tags: html, css, youtube, youtube-api

I want my embed Youtube default resolution to be 1080p. Here is the iframe code:

```
<iframe width="1050" height="591" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/GjsBjsWXgsA?rel=0&vq=hd1080" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The HD1080 works fine on Mozilla Firefox but not on Chrome.

Can anybody suggest other option?

Comment: try to wrap `iframe`  inside a `div`. Might be this link help you. http://demosthenes.info/blog/717/Force-Embedded-YouTube-Videos-To-Play-In-HD

Comment: nope, that's making the video stretch on mobiles and etc..

Answer (score 0):

The following parameters are supported in the AS2 player but have been deprecated for the newer AS3 and HTML5 players: border, color1, color2, egm, **hd**, and showsearch.